# Telnet connection refused

Tags: networking, services, telnet, port

I have been trying to connect using `telnet`. I keep on getting `Connection refused`.

After checking ports listening, I observed the port is listening to the localhost IP 127.0.0.1 but I wanted it to listen to any IP. So how do I detach it from the localhost and make any?

- 127.0.0.1:xxxx I want to replace this with the 0.0.0.0:xxx
- I have disabled both firewall and still have it that way

Please, how do I fix this?

Comment: "the port is listening to the localhost IP" makes no sense. What software is listening to port *xxxx* (why is that hidden?) on 127.0.0.1 - perhaps you need to configure that telnet daemon? also, why have you tagged `ssh` if you want `telnet`?

Comment: What service is running on the xxxx? If it's telnetd, then why are you running an obsolete and network-insecure login service?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

The likely reasons are that `telnetd` service isn't available in the target, or firewall or other security measure is blocking the access.

[Telnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet) is an inherently insecure protocol. `telnetd` isn't included in the modern systems at all by default. When `telnetd` isn't running, `telnet localhost` results in

```
pg1@TREX:~$ telnet localhost
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Trying ::1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Cannot assign requested address
```

When connecting to a remote server with no `telnetd` running, `telnet <serverIP>` results in

```
pg1@TREX:~$ telnet 192.168.1.200
Trying 192.168.1.200...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

So if you explicitly need to use `telnet` you first need to install and run `telnetd` service.

Due to it's insecurity usage of Telnet is not recommended. The industry standard CLI connection method is [SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) (Secure SHell). SSH client is included with every Linux distribution. SSH server might not be, but [OpenSSH](https://www.openssh.com/) server is available in the distribution repos. There are also other alternatives, like the lightweight [Dropbear](https://matt.ucc.asn.au/dropbear/dropbear.html). However before diving into alternatives one should learn the standard SSH first.